# Move div from mid to top in all screens

Tags: jquery

I have a menu in the mid of my web and I want to move it to top on click. The website is this: http://inopia.net/attis/ and I have this code to the movement onClick

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#menuentero').click(function() {
$('#menu, #clickme, .logo-abajo').animate({
   marginTop: '-25.8%'
 }, 750, function() {

});
});
});
```

Where is the problem? The menu goes top onClick, of course but only in my screen with my resolution. In others screen sometimes it goes off the page sometimes it is short. I thought using % should solve this problem but it didnt. So I ask you guys what should I do?

Any help or guidane would be apreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: percentage value is relative to which div in your case. May you should use top:30% or whatever to make sure it doesn't go off the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the margin for the body also.

So, first step is to add this to your CSS:

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

And after that, to use top: 0 instead of margin-top: -25%. Always try to be consistent when moving things around in your page (if you use top / left, stick to that, do not mix it up with margins):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#menuentero').click(function() {
      $('#menu, #clickme, .logo-abajo').animate({
         top: '0'
       }, 750, function() {

      });
   });
});
```

And maybe try to wrap #menu, #clickme and .logo-abajo in a single div, and move only THAT one, so you don`t animate 3 different elements.

Comment: That was the solution! Thanks @RazvanDH. As you may notice I am a beginner in scripting so I dont know mostly things. Is there a problem animating the 3 divs at the time?

Comment: Not a really big problem, but an optimization issue. Basically, you are doing that jQuery animation 3 times (for each element there is an animation triggered). If you wrap them in one div, then you will have only one animation triggered, but with the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You want the style of your `<div>` to include the following.

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:50%;
```

These settings will put your `<div>` in the top middle of any screen.

Comment: @Manuls I understood your question, but I did not write out your answer 100% for you so you would learn something by applying the solution.